# Unable to draw on canvas at the correct position when canvas dimensions are not known in advance

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas, html5-video

We need to draw using mouse on video element. I am using Canvas to render the drawing. When we don't know the video width and height in advance, I am unable to draw the line at the correct position. It is being drawn at different positions. Below is the code.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css" />
</head>

<body>

  <h1>Realtime communication with WebRTC</h1>

  <div id="videos">
    <video id="localVideo" autoplay muted></video>
    <video id="remoteVideo" autoplay></video>
  </div>

  <canvas id="localCanvas"></canvas>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**main.css**

```
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

video {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 320px;
}

canvas {
  position: absolute;
}
```

**main.js**

```
'use strict';
var localVideo = document.querySelector('#localVideo');

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
  audio: false,
  video: true
})
.then(gotStream)
.catch(function(e) {
  alert('getUserMedia() error: ' + e.name);
});

function gotStream(stream) {
  // Checking Whether video is ready to set canvas width and height
  var b = setInterval(() => {
    if(localVideo.readyState >= 3){
          document.getElementById('localCanvas').style.width = document.querySelector('#localVideo').offsetWidth + "px";
          document.getElementById('localCanvas').style.height = document.querySelector('#localVideo').offsetHeight + "px";
          clearInterval(b);
        }
    },500);

  localVideo.srcObject = stream;
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
  let xPos = window.scrollX + document.querySelector('#localVideo').getBoundingClientRect().left;
  let yPos = window.scrollY + document.querySelector('#localVideo').getBoundingClientRect().top;

  document.getElementById('localCanvas').style.left = xPos + "px";
  document.getElementById('localCanvas').style.top = yPos + "px";

  document.getElementById('localCanvas').style.width = document.querySelector('#localVideo').offsetWidth + "px";
  document.getElementById('localCanvas').style.height = document.querySelector('#localVideo').offsetHeight + "px";

  InitThis();
});

var mousePressed = false;
var lastX, lastY;
var ctx;

function InitThis() {
    ctx = document.getElementById('localCanvas').getContext("2d");
    const canvas = document.querySelector('#localCanvas');

    $('#localCanvas').mousedown(function (e) {
        mousePressed = true;
        Draw(e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft, e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop, false);
    });

    $('#localCanvas').mousemove(function (e) {
        if (mousePressed) {
            Draw(e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft, e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop, true);
        }
    });

    $('#localCanvas').mouseup(function (e) {
        mousePressed = false;
    });
        $('#localCanvas').mouseleave(function (e) {
        mousePressed = false;
    });
}

function Draw(x, y, isDown) {
    if (isDown) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.strokeStyle = "blue";
        ctx.lineWidth = 9;
        ctx.lineJoin = "round";
        ctx.moveTo(lastX, lastY);
        ctx.lineTo(x, y);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.stroke();
    }
    lastX = x; lastY = y;
}
```

Here we are just setting max width and width properties in CSS and we don't know the height in advance. So when the onload event listener function, I am setting the width and height coordinates of the canvas based on the localVideo. But by that time Video height is 160 px. But when video is loaded, the height is getting changed to 240 px. So again, I am changing the width and height of Canvas when video state is ready to play as below in gotStream().

```
var b = setInterval(() => {
        if(localVideo.readyState >= 3){
              document.getElementById('localCanvas').style.width = document.querySelector('#localVideo').offsetWidth + "px";
              document.getElementById('localCanvas').style.height = document.querySelector('#localVideo').offsetHeight + "px";
              clearInterval(b);
            }
        },500);
```

Once the video is ready to play, Canvas size is exact same size of localVideo. But when I tried to draw using mouse on canvas, it is being drawn at incorrect positions, Especially when I tried to draw at the bottom half or at the right edge of the Canvas. Can anyone please help me how to fix this issue.

**Update:** I hardcoded the height of Canvas to '240px' in onload event which is also not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canvas is getting stretched because the width and height are being set to style not to the original properties. Fixed the problem by below code.

```
document.getElementById('localCanvas').setAttribute("width", document.querySelector('#localVideo').offsetWidth;
document.getElementById('localCanvas').setAttribute("height", document.querySelector('#localVideo').offsetHeight;
```